# How to add many tab in a function of redmine tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

How can i add many tab like settings function in projects menu bar when i created new redmine plugin. It have many tab: 'Information, Modules, Members, Version,

Answer (score 0):

just add two line in init.rb

```
 menu :project_menu, :polls1, { :controller => 'polls', :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Polls1',:last => true,  :param => :project_id
 menu :project_menu, :polls2, { :controller => 'polls', :action => 'index' }, :caption => 'Polls2',:last => true,  :param => :project_id
```

notice that the second param (:polls1 in line 1 and :polls2 in line 2) can not be the same , or it will raise an error

Comment: Hi leo108,this code to add new plugin to project menu bar, but i want to add many tabs in each project function.